# JavaWS Configure Dependencies

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, maven

Anybody can help me? I need to know the name of dependency of Maven of @EndpointConfig to JBossAS 7.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.ws.native</groupId>
    <artifactId>jbossws-native-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.2.GA</version>
</dependency>
```